# IE <object> z-index issue. wmode transparent doesn't work

Tags: html, internet-explorer, object, pdf, z-index

I am having an IE z-index issue.  Basically, I'm embedding a pdf using the  tag, but in IE, our favourite of favourite browsers it always appears above the drop down menu.

I have the same problem when using .

I've tried the solutions offered online, but they haven't worked.

The problem is at this address: http://www.berkeley.ac.th/calendar/2013-2014.php

This is my code:

```
<object data="<?php echo root; ?>media/3.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="957" height="1080">
     <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
     Our Calendar : <a href="<?php echo root; ?>media/3.pdf">2012-2013 Calendar</a>
 </object>
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried wmode opaque?

Comment: Yes, i have tried.  Unfortunately it gives me the same problem.

Comment: yeah, dstorey, we've gone live now, so it's at www.berkeley.ac.th/calendar/2013-2014.php now.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I decided to go without pdfs, and convert them into images to avoid the whole problem.  This seemed the best move.

Answer (score 0):

try to add wmode transparent like this

> `<script>
>        $(document).ready(function (){
>       $("object").each(function(){
>           var url = $(this).attr("src")
>           $(this).attr("src",url+"?wmode=transparent")
>       });
>       });
>
>   </script>`

Answer (score -2):

Tell them to upgrade to a better browser lol! Also, have you tried iframes? Lots of similar elements but they might work differently.